# Comparing two pandas series element-wise given a specific value

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas series

```
0      0
1      0
2      1
3      0
4      1
      ..
122    0
123    1
124   -1
125    0
126   -1
Name: label_next_day, Length: 127, dtype: int64

0      0
1      0
2      0
3      0
4      0
      ..
122    0
123    1
124    1
125    0
126    1
Name: moda, Length: 127, dtype: int64
```

I want to know the number of corresponding equal values in these two Series but considering a specific value. For example, how many corresponding values are equal and both of them have value 1. I checked Series .eq() and .equals() and they don't solve my problem. How to do that with Python?

Comment: `(s1.eq(s2) & s1.eq(1)).sum()`?

Comment: It works like a charm! if you answer the question, I will mark your solution the one that helped me. Thank you!